# Branch on a pgfopts boolean choice inside a newcommand?

Tags: macros, conditionals, pgfkeys

Consider the following code for a class that relies on `pgfopts` for option management:

```
% CLASS
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/11]
\LoadClass{standalone}
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    myoption/.is choice,
    myoption/true/.code = {\newcommand{\myclass@myoption}{true}},% newcommand or renewcommand?
    myoption/false/.code = {\newcommand{\myclass@myoption}{false}},% newcommand or renewcommand?
    myoption/.default = true,% default or initial?
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/myclass}

% Things to modify
\def\myclass@true{true}% I would like to avoid to have to define this
\def\myclass@false{false}% I would like to avoid to have to define this
\newcommand{\myclass@displayboolean}[1]{%
    \ifx\myclass@myoption\myclass@true% This seems to fail
        \fbox{\texttt{MY OPTION = TRUE}}%
    \else%
        \fbox{\texttt{MY OPTION = FALSE}}%
    \fi%
}

% This has to stay the same if possible
\newcommand{\printmyoption}{\myclass@displayboolean{\myoption}}
\makeatother
```

and the following use of it:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\printmyoption
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[myoption = true]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\printmyoption
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[myoption = false]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\printmyoption
\end{document}
```

---

**PROBLEM:** In all cases it outputs `MY OPTION = FALSE` so I guess the test in the command `\myclass@displayboolean` fails. I tried several things but I haven't find the right way to do it yet.

**QUESTION:** How to correctly define `myoption` as a boolean choice, and how to correctly branch on it inside a macro?

Comment: Is there a reason for the rather odd boolean setup? Why not use `.is if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `\newcommand`, which makes 'long' macros (that can take a `\par` token in arguments), then comparing against a macro created with `\def`, which is 'short'. Even though the two macros do not take any arguments, they are no `\ifx` equal as a result. Use the same method to save your tokens and your comparison version:

```latex
\newcommand*\myclass@myoption{}
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    myoption/.is choice,
    myoption/true/.code = {\def\myclass@myoption{true}},
    myoption/false/.code = {\def\myclass@myoption{false}},
    myoption/.default = true,
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete code for the whole class?

Comment: @Vincent The change I've made above is the only difference from your example

Comment: The `myoption/.default` does not seem to work. When I just load the class with no parameters, it prints `MY OPTION = FALSE`.

Comment: @Vincent The `.default` is what is used if you give `myoption` without a value; if you want to 'set up front', you want `.initial`.

Comment: I tried `myoption/.initial = true` but it does not seem to work either...

Comment: @Vincent Ah, as you've set it up as a choice, `pgf` 'thinks` about this slightly differently: you need `myoption = true`

Comment: Thanks that works!